# Reference request and a question for a operator inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, reference-request, mathematical-physics

It is difficult for me to explain the background of this question, but I would like to know the following statement is true or not:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $A, B \in B(H)$ be self-adjoint and non-negative.
> Then, $(A+B)^s \leq A^s + B^s$ for any $s \in [0, 1]$.

Lately, I have often encountered such kind of *operator inequalities.*
There are many papers that deal with this type of issue, but I don't know any good textbook.
I would appreciate it if you could point me to an appropriate textbook.

Comment: Odd, is that taken from a paper? Is it not proved or referenced??

Comment: It’s true for scalars. Is there some applicable functional calculus that saves the day

Comment: @CalvinKhor Not if $A$ and $B$ don't commute. Such inequalities are usually considerably harder than their scalar versions and often false (such as the convexity of $A\mapsto A^p$ for $p>2$).

Comment: @Paul I'm sorry. This is not taken from a paper. This is an inequality that I wish could be established.